# Secure a webapi2 project to be called from another project or website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 projects an mvc5 & webapi. I am wanting to call the api from a pure clientside manor even though im using mvc (I am slowing trying to migrate old code into a spa like application still being able to maintain the current codebase).

The url of the api sits under the main domain e.g. subdomain.mydomain.com/api so I dont have to worry about jsonp or crossdomain stuff.

How do I secure the api. Am I right in thinking when a user logs into the mvc5 application there is there some kind of key or token I can access. I store it somewhere on the site and add it in the request header?

If I follow this approach how do I validate the token at the api end. An actionfilter that reads the header? or is there a cleaner method.

The only information I can really find on using the api is to use basic auth which is something I dont really want to have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice simple(ish) way to do it is to use a token based method.  So the client authenticates once, you give them a token, then subsequent requests pass the token and the server checks it.

It does require some custom code, but I have seen a few good examples.  Here is one that I loosely followed:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API

It enforces HTTPS, then does the token generating and validation after that.